# Did Dab Hantaq always look like Anakin Solo?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

During the Yuuzhan Vong War, traitorous senator Viqi Shesh recruited a young Coruscant boy named [**Dab Hantaq**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dab_Hantaq) to distract Han & Leia Solo. When he first appears, it's mentioned that Viqi paid a fortune for him to look like Anakin Solo (presumably via plastic surgery), and this is backed up in the Wookieepedia article I'm linking to. However, later books seem to indicate that Shesh recruited the boy for the very REASON that he looked like Anakin Solo.

**So, did Dab Hantaq always resemble Anakin Solo, or was he altered to look that way?**

Comment: Maybe he looked _a lot_ like Anakin, but he was surgically altered to look _exactly_ like him.